# HTTPError : HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when download MNIST dataset using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

## Please help me to solve this problem

I am using colab notebook and loaded it to my drive. When I run the following code to get the dataset using the following code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root="/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/pytorch/Data",
                                           train=True, 
                                           transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                                           download=True
                                           )
```

This is my error

```
Downloading http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz to /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/pytorch/Data/MNIST/raw/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
0/? [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-32702cf15284> in <module>()
      3                                            train=True,
      4                                            transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
----> 5                                            download=True
      6                                            )

11 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

i also faced similar issue and i resolve it by normalizing the data not sure though why it works try this.

```
enter code heretrain_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root="/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/pytorch/Data",
                                       train=True, 
                                       transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))]),
                                       download=True
                                       )
```